# Are there better alternatives to the following javascript construct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, coding-style

The following code pattern is how I'm constructing my AJAX system. I'm concerned about when more prototype property is added. This could take a hit on maintainability and efficiency.

Are there better alternative ways to go about creating a maintainable and efficient construct for AJAX?

```
function AjaxSample()
{
    //bindJS() is used to bind the 'this' pointer to the scope of the function
    $('#button_one').click(bindJS(this.button_oneEvent,this)); 
} 

AjaxSample.prototype.button_oneEvent = function(event)
{
    //code to handle the event
}
```

Comment: Note that modern browsers have a "bind()" function on the Function prototype, which does exactly what your "bindJS" function does. There's nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: I'm also taking into account that most of my users will be on IE6.

Comment: Well @samxli that's ok, your "bindJS" function will work on IE6 just fine, or you could add it to the Function prototype like the Prototype.js library does.

Comment: oh, I'm actually not using the Prototype.js library, I'm using jquery.

Comment: Well that's fine - jQuery has "$.proxy()" (since 1.4 or so) which also does exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
var self = this;
$('#button_one').click(function() {
    self.button_oneEvent();
});
```

Using this technique it's more obvious what's actually happending.

Comment: I don't see why this is better than what's in the question. The "bindJS" function presumably returns an anonymous function that ends up doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: I don't think this is "more obvouis". This is a matter of style.